# How to add more than 25 choices to autocomplete option discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to create an option that has autocomplete but works with more than 25 choices, I've seen other bots do it I'm just lost on how I would be able to do that. I have the basic autocomplete setup already it just won't let me add more than 25 choices. I'm using discord.js v14 (I have 28 options added rn, it only works with 25 though. Ty in advance!)

```js
        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "botanical" ) { 
            const focusedOption = interaction.options.getFocused(true);
            let choices;

            if (focusedOption.name === 'search') {
                choices = ['agrimony', 'allspice', 'almond', 'aloe', 'anise', 'apple', 'avocado', 'basil', 'bayLaurel', 'bergamot', 'birch', 'calendula', 'cardamom', 'chamomile', 'cinnamon', 'comfrey', 'hemp', 'lavender', 'mint', 'motherwort', 'mugwort', 'rose', 'rosemary', 'sage', 'thyme', 'valerian', 'vervain', 'yarrow', 'valerian', 'vervain', 'yarrow'];
            }
            const filtered = choices.filter(choice => choice.startsWith(focusedOption.value));
            await interaction.respond(
                filtered.map(choice => ({ name: choice, value: choice })),
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is actually very close to being able to achieve your desired functionality; all you need to do now is to slice the filtered array to only show up to 25 so that it won't yield an error initially:

```
if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "botanical" ) { 
        const focusedOption = interaction.options.getFocused(true);
        let choices;

        if (focusedOption.name === 'search') {
            choices = ['agrimony', 'allspice', 'almond', 'aloe', 'anise', 'apple', 'avocado', 'basil', 'bayLaurel', 'bergamot', 'birch', 'calendula', 'cardamom', 'chamomile', 'cinnamon', 'comfrey', 'hemp', 'lavender', 'mint', 'motherwort', 'mugwort', 'rose', 'rosemary', 'sage', 'thyme', 'valerian', 'vervain', 'yarrow', 'valerian', 'vervain', 'yarrow'];
         }
        const filtered = choices.filter(choice => choice.startsWith(focusedOption.value));

        let options;
        if (filtered.length > 25) {
            options = filtered.slice(0, 25);
        } else {
            options = filtered;
        }

        await interaction.respond(
            options.map(choice => ({ name: choice, value: choice })),
        );
    }
```

There's probably a tighter way you could write the above, but just for the sake of answering this question, I've integrated the slicing portion with an additional `options` variable to maintain what you've already written above.

Hope this helps!

**Addendum**:

Something else you may want to do is make it so that you make the `focusedOption` case-insenstive by doing something like `focusedOption.value.toLowerCase()` in the filter function.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up finding a discord.py solution for this that is pretty similar, if anyone else was looking for it.

When using the rps_autocomplete function to set the choices for a command, you can set it up to slice the filtered array to only show 25 at a time. I am now able to have 100+ autocomplete choices and counting.

```
async def rps_autocomplete(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, current: str) -> List[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
    with open('./choices.json') as f:
        choices = json.load(f)['choices'] 
    choices = [app_commands.Choice(name=choice, value=choice) for choice in choices if current.lower() in choice.lower()][:25]
    return choices
```

You can then set the choices in your command by calling the rps_autocomplete function:

```
@app_commands.autocomplete(something=rps_autocomplete)
async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, something: str):
```

You can also set the choices to a list instead of a .json, but I found if it is a bit long it can take up some unnecessary space on the command file.

Comment: The question is about discord.js.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you can't. Discord has a 25-option limit on this, nothing you can do to get around it or add more than 25 options to one selector