# How to add more than 25 choices to Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was wondering if it was possible to bypass the 25 choices limit for autocomplete options to allow for more options.

I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73449317/how-to-add-more-than-25-choices-to-autocomplete-option-discord-js-v14) from last year that sliced the choices list if it was greater than 25 and I tried to do it myself, but it did not show any of the options at all when using the command.

Here is the code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('test')
        .setDescription('testing')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('option')
                .setDescription('The option to select')
                .setRequired(true)
                .setAutocomplete(true)),
    async autocomplete(interaction) {
        const focusedOption = interaction.options.getFocused(true);
        let choices;
         if (focusedOption.name === 'option') {
         choices = ['Apple','Orange','Banana','Grapes','Pomegranate','Watermelon','Passionfruit','Grapefruit','Tomato','Dragonfruit','Strawberry','Blueberry','Rasberry','Blackberry','Kiwi','Lemon','Lime','Gooseberry','Guava','Tangerine','Mango','Tomato','Starfruit','Pineapple','Jackfruit','Coconut','Chilli'];
         }
        const filtered = choices.filter(choice => choice.startsWith(focusedOption.value));
         let options;
        if (filtered.length > 25) {
            options = filtered.slice(0, 25);
        } else {
            options = filtered;
        }
        await interaction.respond(
            filtered.map(choice => ({ name: choice, value: choice })),
        );
    },
    async execute(interaction){
        interaction.reply(interaction.options.getString('option'));
    }
};
```

Comment: So you removed the if block that sliced it?

Answer (score 0):

`filtered.map` should be `options.map` if `options` is the filtered array that has max 25 items.

Anyway, you could simplify it. `slice(0, 25)` will always return a new array with a max of 25 items. If it has 10 items, it just copies the array with that 10 items. If it has 30 items, it returns the first 25 items.

```js
async autocomplete(interaction) {
  const focusedOption = interaction.options.getFocused(true);
  let choices = [];
  if (focusedOption.name === 'search')
    choices = ['Apple','Orange','Banana','Grapes','Pomegranate','Watermelon','Passionfruit','Grapefruit','Tomato','Dragonfruit','Strawberry','Blueberry','Rasberry','Blackberry','Kiwi','Lemon','Lime','Gooseberry','Guava','Tangerine','Mango','Tomato','Starfruit','Pineapple','Jackfruit','Coconut','Chilli'];

  const filtered = choices
    .filter((choice) => choice.startsWith(focusedOption.value))
    .slice(0, 25);

  await interaction.respond(
    filtered.map((choice) => ({ name: choice, value: choice })),
  );
},
```

Comment: Thanks that might work. But now, I am getting the error: 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')'.  Is there something wrong with the code inside the filter function?

Comment: I've changed it to `let choices = []` so the default is an empty array.

Comment: It now shows the choices in the option menu and they work, but it only shows 25 of them, and when I try to search it says 'Loading Options Failed'

Comment: do you know of any way to fix this? I've been stuck the past 2 weeks and it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert the choices into lowercase or else you will only see the initial 25 values and not the value that is searched.

So your code will look like this:

```js
const filtered = choices
  .filter((choice) => choice.toLowerCase().startsWith(focusedOption.value))
  .slice(0, 25);
```