# How to code a slice choice option for 25 options via their searches

Tags: discord.js

I have a Discord.JS bot that sends vehicles, colors, and license plate text to a database although the vehicles I have I listed as Choice Options, I was informed that there were 25 choice options as a limit and I have 290+ choice options, I want this to be dynamic in a way which thoroughly does their search for that specific vehicle via 25 options, as I want to keep those vehicles in order to work, I saw this being possible in [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76606881/how-to-add-more-than-25-choices-to-autocomplete) and [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73449317/how-to-add-more-than-25-choices-to-autocomplete-option-discord-js-v14), any assistance would be great as I want to get this up and running! Thanks.

(lowered the amount of choice options so people wouldn't need to scroll up & down as much.)

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const Vehicle = require('../../models/vehicle.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'register',
  description: 'Register a new vehicle',
  options: [
    {
      name: 'vehicle',
      type: 'STRING',
      description: 'Type of vehicle to register (e.g., Car, Bike, Truck)',
      required: true,
      choices: [
        { name: '2005 Handa Integra Type R', value: '2005 Handa Integra Type R' },
        { name: '2017 Aero Nomad Tactical', value: '2017 Aero Nomad Tactical' },
        { name: '2021 Owdi RS5', value: '2021 Owdi RS5' },
        { name: '2011 BNW 1M', value: '2011 BNW 1M' },
        // Add more vehicle options here
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'color',
      type: 'STRING',
      description: 'Color of the vehicle',
      required: true,
      choices: [
        { name: 'Red', value: 'Red' },
        { name: 'Blue', value: 'Blue' },
        { name: 'Green', value: 'Green' },
        { name: 'Yellow', value: 'Yellow' },
        { name: 'White', value: 'White' },
        { name: 'Black', value: 'Black' },
        { name: 'Gray', value: 'Gray' },
        { name: 'Purple', value: 'Purple' },
        { name: 'Pink', value: 'Pink' },
        { name: 'Orange', value: 'Orange' },
        { name: 'Gold', value: 'Gold' }
        // Add more color options here
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'licenseplate',
      type: 'STRING',
      description: 'License Plate of the vehicle (maximum 6 characters)',
      required: true,
      validate: (value) => {
        if (!value) return 'License plate cannot be empty.';
        if (value.length > 6) return 'License plate must not exceed 6 characters.';
        return true;
      },
    },
  ],
  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const vehicleType = interaction.options.getString('vehicle');
    const vehicleColor = interaction.options.getString('color');
    const licensePlate = interaction.options.getString('licenseplate'); // Get the value of the license plate
    const ownerId = interaction.user.id;

    try {
      // Fetch the vehicles owned by the user from the database
      const userVehicles = await Vehicle.find({ ownerId });

      // Check if the user has a certain role with a vehicle limit
      const userRoles = interaction.member.roles.cache;
      const roleWithLimit = '1130315595645194330'; // Replace 'YOUR_ROLE_ID' with the actual role ID that has a limit of 6 vehicles

      let vehicleLimit = 3;
      if (userRoles.some(role => role.id === roleWithLimit)) {
        vehicleLimit = 6;
      }

      if (userVehicles.length >= vehicleLimit) {
        return interaction.reply({ content: `You have reached the maximum limit of ${vehicleLimit} vehicles for your role.`, ephemeral: true });
      }

      // Save the selected vehicle to the database with the user's ID, color, and license plate
      const vehicle = new Vehicle({
        ownerId,
        name: vehicleType,
        type: vehicleType,
        color: vehicleColor,
        licensePlate: licensePlate, // Save the license plate in the database
      });

      await vehicle.save();

      // Show a confirmation message
      interaction.reply({ content: `Successfully registered a new ${vehicleColor} ${vehicleType} with license plate ${licensePlate}!`, ephemeral: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error while saving vehicle to database:', error);
      interaction.reply({ content: 'An error occurred while processing the command.', ephemeral: true });
    }
  },
};
```

I was expecting this to work although it seems it didn't work at all and just gave me the same 25 choice option limit.

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const Vehicle = require('../../models/vehicle.js');

const vehicleChoices = [
  { name: '2005 Handa Integra Type R', value: '2005 Handa Integra Type R' },
  { name: '2017 Aero Nomad Tactical', value: '2017 Aero Nomad Tactical' },
  { name: '2021 Owdi RS5', value: '2021 Owdi RS5' },
  { name: '2011 BNW 1M', value: '2011 BNW 1M' },
  // Add more vehicle choices here
  // ...
  { name: '2019 Chavy Corvette Z06', value: '2019 Chavy Corvette Z06' },
];

module.exports = {
  name: 'register',
  description: 'Register a new vehicle',
  options: [
    {
      name: 'vehicle',
      type: 'STRING',
      description: 'Type of vehicle to register (e.g., Car, Bike, Truck)',
      required: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'color',
      type: 'STRING',
      description: 'Color of the vehicle',
      required: true,
      choices: [
        { name: 'Red', value: 'Red' },
        { name: 'Blue', value: 'Blue' },
        { name: 'Green', value: 'Green' },
        // Add more color options here
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'licenseplate',
      type: 'STRING',
      description: 'License Plate of the vehicle (maximum 6 characters)',
      required: true,
      validate: (value) => {
        if (!value) return 'License plate cannot be empty.';
        if (value.length > 6) return 'License plate must not exceed 6 characters.';
        return true;
      },
    },
  ],
  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const vehicleType = interaction.options.getString('vehicle');
    const vehicleColor = interaction.options.getString('color');
    const licensePlate = interaction.options.getString('licenseplate'); // Get the value of the license plate
    const ownerId = interaction.user.id;

    try {
      // Filter vehicle choices based on user input
      const filteredChoices = vehicleChoices.filter((choice) =>
        choice.name.toLowerCase().includes(vehicleType.toLowerCase())
      );

      // Display up to 25 similar options
      const choices = filteredChoices.slice(0, 25).map((choice) => ({
        name: choice.name,
        value: choice.value,
      }));

      // Save the selected vehicle to the database with the user's ID, color, and license plate
      const vehicle = new Vehicle({
        ownerId,
        name: vehicleType,
        type: vehicleType,
        color: vehicleColor,
        licensePlate: licensePlate,
      });

      await vehicle.save();

      // Show a confirmation message
      interaction.reply({ content: `Successfully registered a new ${vehicleColor} ${vehicleType} with license plate ${licensePlate}!`, ephemeral: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error while processing the command:', error);
      interaction.reply({ content: 'An error occurred while processing the command.', ephemeral: true });
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up an autocomplete check in `interactionCreate` event:

```js
if (interaction.isAutocomplete()) { // ...
```

2. Create a `choices` array of objects (`{ name: string, value: string | number }`);
3. Respond in this way:

```js
// get the focused option entered by the user.
const focused = interaction.options.getFocused();

// filter out choices matching the focused option & keep only 25.
const filtered = choices.filter(c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(focused.toLowerCase())).slice(0, 25);

// respond with new choices
await interaction.respond(filtered.map(c => ({ name: c.name, value: c.value })));
```